# AngularJS: display a select box from JSON data retrieved by http GET (from REST service)

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest, angularjs

I have a REST service that I made which returns a json string which is simply a set of strings (I used Gson to generate this string (Gson.toJson(mySetOfStrings))

So I have added to my index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="ListOptionsCtrl">
  <form novalidate>
    <button ng-click="refreshList()">refresh</button>
    <select name="option" ng-model="form.option" ng-options="o.n for o in optionsList></select>
  </form>
</div>
```

and in my script:

```
var ListOptionsCtrl = function ListOptionsCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.refreshList = function() {
    $http({ 
      method: 'GET'
      url: '*someurl*'
    }).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.optionsList = angular.fromJson(data);
    });
  };
}
```

Unfortunately all this produces in my select box is an empty list. When I see what the response to the GET request is it returns a json string with content in it so I do not see why nothing is being added to this element. What am I doing wrong here? thanks

Comment: You should use `ngResource`. Angular will automatically parse the JSON for you.  Note if the JSON is a list, you would use `.query()`

Comment: ^ Agreed. Just set optionsList = data; And if that doesn't work we would need to see what your json object looks like.

Comment: Could you provide your json array structure?

Answer (score 0):

It is because Angular does not know about your changes yet. Because Angular allow any value to be used as a binding target. Then at the end of any JavaScript code turn, check to see if the value has changed.

You need to use $apply

```
var ListOptionsCtrl = function ListOptionsCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.refreshList = function() {
    $http({ 
      method: 'GET'
      url: '*someurl*'
    }).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.optionsList = angular.fromJson(data);
        });
    });
  };
}
```

Try this.

More about how it works and why it is needed at [Jim Hoskins's post](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Comment: I believe $http handles $apply() automatically. Having $scope.$apply() inside of $htpp will throw a '$digest already in progress' error.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for $digest error by doing if(!$scope.$$phase) { ... } before doing $apply.

```
success(function(data) {
     if(!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.optionsList = angular.fromJson(data);
        });
      }
    });
```